# ionic stuck on splash screen after updating app from Apple App Store

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an iOS app that whenever I publish an update to the apple app store, upon updating the app it gets stuck on the splash screen forever. Users have to uninstall the app and then download it again and it works again. What could this be? Maybe a conflict with the Ionic Pro live update feature? I just do ionic cordova build ios --prod and then archive that in xcode and upload it. Has anyone seen this or could provide some info? I have been able to reproduce this in the simulator just once, the output is:

```
2018-09-12 08:11:04.984076-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.5 is starting.
2018-09-12 08:11:04.985122-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-09-12 08:11:05.006231-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2018-09-12 08:11:05.595907-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2018-09-12 08:11:05.596117-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] Using Ionic WKWebView
2018-09-12 08:11:05.597015-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][console] 0.097990ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.597364-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.159979ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.600208-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 2.681017ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.600456-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.082970ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.606008-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][file] 5.420923ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.623266-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 17.089963ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.623982-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][ioniccordovacommon] 0.558019ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.624276-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2018-09-12 08:11:05.625319-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.165986ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.635999-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 10.508060ms
2018-09-12 08:11:05.636167-0500 Partners SL[34884:1454769] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 39.312959ms
```

And then stays there forever, the device shows splash screen and spinner.
I open the safari dev tools and there is nothing in the console. Network shows a single request to http://localhost:8080/ but it is not even red. It has no status or source.

If I click on the refresh icon on top of the safari dev tool (or refresh via javascript) I get localhost:8080 404 not found in red.

The elements tab just shows empty head and body tags. No content at all. Seems like the app is not even loading the JS files.

Ionic info is as follows:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, ios 4.5.5

System:

   ios-deploy : 2.0.0
   NodeJS     : v10.8.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.2.0
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

If I delete the app from the simulator device, and build and run again, it works fine. This is the weirdest part.

Thanks! Hope someone can help!